# How to customize Ubuntu on laptop lid close behavior

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, hibernate

I would like to learn how to customize the behavior of Ubuntu when the laptop lid closes. I can only guess that a script is run when the laptop lid is closed.

Is there a tutorial/literature explaining what script gets run upon the laptop lid closing / re-opening? I would like to ultimately customize it so I can make my laptop hibernate whenever the lid is closed.

On a longer note, learning which scripts get called, or the hooks into the operating system that allow the OS to be customized for the hardware it runs on is the more substantial goal. I'm using this problem of my laptop not hibernating as a means to learn that.

Comment: Check out this link : http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/04/13/shutdown-hibernate-ubuntu-17-04-lid-closed/ is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for responding. Your link gave me new leads to follow, thanks.